# Why do I get exception when checking for open Serial Port?

Tags: c#, combobox, serial-port

I am trying to check for an open Serial Port, to remove it from comboBox, but I get an Exception on the line checking for Open Serial Port when I click on comboBox dropdown, even if the port is closed. Why does this happen? Please Help! here is my Code. The exception says: 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred. If the if condition is true, when serialport1 is open, then there is no exception. why?!

```
    private void comboBox9_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load Com Port List into comboBoxes when dropdown. Holds list actual
        comboBox9.Items.Clear();
        string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
        foreach (var portName in portNames)
        {
            comboBox9.Items.Add(portName);

            //Removes comboBox entry if port is Open
            if (_serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                comboBox9.Items.Remove(_serialPort1.PortName);
            }

        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I got it now. Here is the actual code and it does what it should do.
It refreshes the comboBox entries and removes the open ports from list.

```
    private void comboBox9_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox9.Items.Clear();
        string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
        foreach (var portName in portNames)
        {
            comboBox9.Items.Add(portName);
        }
        if (_serialPort1 != null && _serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            comboBox9.Items.Remove(_serialPort1.PortName);
        }
    }
```